# Representing a function as a power series and finding the coefficients of the terms?

Tags: calculus

My prblem asks me to find the coefficients of the first five terms of the power series representation of the function:

$$f(x)=\frac{10}{17+x}$$

$$f(x)=10*\frac{\frac{1}{17}}{1-\frac{-x}{17}}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}10*\frac{1}{17}*(\frac{-x}{17})^n$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{10}{17}*\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{17^n}$$

First five terms are:

$$\frac{10}{17} + \frac{10}{17}*\frac{-x}{17} + \frac{10}{17}*\frac{x^2}{17^2} + \frac{10}{17}*\frac{-x^3}{17^3} + \frac{10}{17}*\frac{x^4}{17^4}$$

I entered $0$ for the first coefficient. Marked me correct.

I put $\frac{10}{17}$ for the second coefficient. Marked me correct.

I put $\frac{10}{17}$ for the third coefficient. Marked me wrong.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Looking at the series again, the coefficient should be $-\frac{10}{17}$ for the second coefficient, shouldn't it?

I tried a bunch of stuff for the second coefficient too. $0$, $-1$, $1$, $-10$, $10$, $\frac{10}{17}$, $-\frac{10}{17}$, $\frac{100}{17^2}$, $-\frac{100}{17^2}$, $\frac{10}{17^3}$, $-\frac{10}{17^3}$ (those last few are from different ways of writing the power series I tried). Nothing is working. Where am I going wrong?

Edit: to clarify a bit, the question wants me to find the coefficients of $x^0$, $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$ and $x^4$ in the series.

Comment: `-10/17^2` does not seem to be on your list.

Comment: The second coefficient is the whole thing in front of $x^2$.

Comment: @Henry You're right. The correct answers are $0$, $\frac{10}{17}$, $-\frac{10}{17^2}$, $\frac{10}{17^3}$, $-\frac{10}{17^4}$ (I could have sworn I tried those). But why are the even powers negative, and the odd powers positive?

Comment: Because for $|x| \lt 1$ you have $1 + x+x^2+x^3 + \cdots=\frac{1}{1-x}$  (a geometric series) and so $\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x+x^2-x^3 + \cdots$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *coefficients* of the terms of a Maclaurin power series for a function $f(x)$ are numbers $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots$ such that $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$ for all $x$ within the interval of convergence of the series. You got very close to finding them, but unfortunately, didn't quite get all the way there, because you didn't get the powers of $x$ separated from the rest. Since

\begin{eqnarray}f(x) &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{10}{17}\cdot\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{17^n}\\ &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{10\cdot(-1)^nx^n}{17\cdot17^n}\\ &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{10\cdot(-1)^nx^n}{17^{n+1}}\\ &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{10\cdot(-1)^n}{17^{n+1}}x^n,\end{eqnarray} then the coefficients in general have the form $\frac{10\cdot(-1)^n}{17^{n+1}}$ for all $n.$ Hence, the coefficients you're looking for are $$\frac{10}{17},-\frac{10}{17^2},\frac{10}{17^3},-\frac{10}{17^4},\frac{10}{17^5}.$$ I have no idea why $0$ would've been accepted as the first coefficient.

---

**Edit**: Thanks to [your comment below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187443/representing-a-function-as-a-power-series-and-finding-the-coefficients-of-the-te/3187610?noredirect=1#comment6560968_3187610), I see that the actual function in question is $$g(x)=\frac{10x}{17+x}.$$ Letting $f(x)=\frac{10}{17+x}$ be the initially posted function, we see that $g(x)=x\cdot f(x),$ and so $$\begin{eqnarray}g(x) &=& x\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{10\cdot(-1)^n}{17^{n+1}}x^n\\ &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{10\cdot(-1)^n}{17^{n+1}}x^{n+1}\\ &=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{10\cdot(-1)^{n-1}}{17^n}x^n\\ &=& 0x^0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{10\cdot(-1)^{n-1}}{17^n}x^n,\end{eqnarray}$$ whence the first five coefficients are $$0,\frac{10}{17},-\frac{10}{17^2},\frac{10}{17^3},-\frac{10}{17^4}.$$

Comment: 0 is accepted because the first x term is $0x^0$. That's how it was "explained" to me by my professor.

Comment: Also, the correct answer for the _second_ coefficient is $\frac{10}{17^2}$. Any idea why it would be positive and not negative?

Comment: Either your professor is incorrect, or has mis-typed the problem, or you have mis-typed the problem. Assuming that the correct function is $$f(x)=\frac{10}{17+x},$$ your derivation was flawless, but incomplete. Mine took it the rest of the way. For further verification, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maclaurin+series+of+10%2F(17%2Bx)).

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/nvNwXv8AnvLvYnfb9

I'll let you know what her explanation is.

Edit: actually as I just posted that I see 10x is in the numerator instead of just 10. Would that actually change signs though?

Comment: So you've mis-typed the problem. That explains it! I will adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that as I posted the comment. So, now because of  that extra x, it's going to be $x^{n+1}$ later on? And that's going to change the signs?

Comment: No, the signs shouldn't change. The only difference is that the coefficients shift further along in the order, and now we have the first coefficient equal to $0.$

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. Thanks for helping me understand it!

Answer (score 0):

You allready found $$f(x)=\frac{10}{17} + \frac{10}{17}\frac{-x}{17} + \frac{10}{17}\frac{x^2}{17^2} + \frac{10}{17}*\frac{-x^3}{17^3} + \frac{10}{17}\frac{x^4}{17^4}+...$$
$$=\frac{10}{17} - \frac{10}{17^2}x + \frac{10}{17^3}x^2 - \frac{10}{17^4}x^3 + \frac{10}{17^5}x^5 \mp ...$$

The general coefficient $a_n$ is given by

$$a_n=(-1)^n\dfrac{10}{17^{n+1}}.$$